# How to open .jade file directly in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, pug

Is there a plugin for chrome or any other browser which allows for files written in Jade to be directly viewed in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such plugin existed, it would simply use the jade compile function to render the file into an HTML on then serve it to the browser.

As such plugin doesn't exist (yet?), simply use the [command line](http://jade-lang.com/command-line/) to compile the file you want to render manually.

```
jade foo.jade
```

Comment: a Profuse thanks! If only programmers could understand the plight of people learning the awesome art!